# PDF set reading direction when converting to txt

Tags: python-3.x, pdfminer

Is it possible to set the reading direction of the pdf file when converting it to txt. I have a nice code which works well but my pdfs are all writting like in 2 columns. For some pdf the code reads from left to right and for others it read first the left column and then the right column (doing that from left to right) but i want it to read from left to right always not first and then second column.

Has anyone an idea how to set the reading direction ?

**Here an example (see picture below):**
1.15               some text
                   some more text from 1.15
1.16               alot of text 
                   more text for 1.16

**Sometimes i get (always a different file but its always the structure of the example)**
1.15
1.16
some text
some more text from 1.15
alot of text 
more text for 1.16

**other times i get (THS IS WHAT I WANT)**
1.15
some text
some more text from 1.15
1.16
alot of text 
more text for 1.15

here is my code:

```
def pdfparser(data):
    fp = open(data, 'rb')
    resource_manager = PDFResourceManager()
    retstr = io.StringIO()
    codec = 'utf-8'
    pagenos = set(pages)
    laparams = LAParams()
    device = TextConverter(resource_manager, retstr, codec=codec, laparams=laparams)
    interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(resource_manager, device)

    for page in PDFPage.get_pages(fp, pagenos):
        interpreter.process_page(page)
        data = retstr.getvalue()

    file = open(out_file1, "w", encoding='utf-8')
    file.write(data)
    file.close()

pdfparser(filename)
```

[image]

Comment: Where's the image?

Comment: right below the code

Comment: Oh lol looked like straight text